# How to get rid of rendering issue in Android Studio that refers to resource that isn't found in project?

Tags: android

The "Rendering problem" states `Couldn't resolve resource @style/Widget.Holo.Actionmode` but when I do a project/path search for `Widget.Holo.Actionmode` it isn't there.

As a result, my soft numeric keypad won't display.

What the heck do I do? I've changed the styles in the Android Studio 1.1.0 dropdown in design mode but no matter what I choose I get the rendering problem and no keypad. I had colors set to `Holo` this and that because I liked the shades and I had `Holo` as the theme from the dropdown. I also have in `AndroidManifest.xml` this:

`android:theme           ="@style/AppTheme"`

But when it was working, I had commented that out to get nice black background. Either way, no keypad.

All I have in `styles.xml` is this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I exited and re-entered AS. No keypad; same problem.

I'll post all xml and activity java code if need be. This is insane.

Comment: once try to Build->Rebuild & clean Project

Comment: I did that. No help. Still got the "Rendering problems".

Comment: Well, this is amusing: There's an "X" to close the "Rendering problems" window, so I finally did. Now when I run I get the soft number pad and all is well ON MY PHONE, but in EVERY emulator I've set up, there is still no soft number pad but the "Rendering problems" message is gone. No errors.

Comment: Crud. It's prom night. I have to go take pictures so I won't be monitoring this. I'll post a final solution if I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there's a problem in APIs 17 & 18 with the definition of Widget.Holo.ActionMode.  I added the following to my styles.xml file:

```
<!-- Put this here to fix rendering error in API 17-18 -->
<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionMode" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionMode">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

This may happen on APIs below 17, haven't tested.  It was fixed in 19.